# Variables in terragrunt. AWS region selection

Tags: amazon-web-services, terragrunt

I'm trying to create AWS environment using terragrunt. I worked in us-east-2 region and now     I want to work in eu-central-1.
In my code I have the only variable, that represents region. I changed it to eu-central-1, but when I execute "terragrunt run-all plan" I see my old environment in outputs.
I deleted tfstate and all other local files, that were created by terragrunt. I also deleted s3bucket and dynamodb table in AWS. Where does terragrunt store information about region? How can I use new region?

```
terraform {
  source = "/home/bohdan/Dev_ops/terragrunt_vpc/modules//vpc"
  extra_arguments "custom_vars" {
    commands = get_terraform_commands_that_need_vars()
  }
}

locals {
  remote_state_bucket_prefix = "tfstate"
  environment = "dev"
  app_name = "demo3"
  aws_account = "873432059572"
  aws_region = "eu-central-1"
  image_tag = "v1"  
}

inputs = {
  remote_state_bucket = format("%s-%s-%s-%s", local.remote_state_bucket_prefix, local.app_name, local.environment, local.aws_region)
  environment = local.environment
  app_name = local.app_name
  aws_account = local.aws_account
  aws_region = local.aws_region
  image_tag = local.image_tag
}

remote_state {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    encrypt        = true
    bucket         = format("%s-%s-%s-%s", local.remote_state_bucket_prefix, local.app_name, local.environment, local.aws_region)
    key            = format("%s/terraform.tfstate", path_relative_to_include())
    region         = local.aws_region
    # dynamodb_table = format("tflock-%s-%s-%s", local.environment, local.app_name, local.aws_region)
    dynamodb_table = "my-lock-table"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `terragrunt.hcl` file to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in `source = "/home/bohdan/Dev_ops/terragrunt_vpc/modules//vpc"`

I referred to an incorrect module with hardcoded region